# Composing Haskell filters

Tags: haskell, composition, applicative

I am converting the [zxcvbn password strength](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) algorithm to Haskell.

I have two functions that check for all characters being ASCII and that a brute force attack is possible:

```
filterAscii :: [String] -- ^terms to filter
            -> [String] -- ^filtered terms
filterAscii = filter $ all (\ chr -> ord chr < 128)
```

and

```
filterShort :: [String] -- ^terms to filter
            -> [String] -- ^filtered terms
filterShort terms = map fst $ filter long $ zip terms [1..]
  where long (term, index) = (26 ^ length term) > index
```

I composed these into a single function:

```
filtered :: [String] -- ^terms to filter
         -> [String] -- ^filtered terms
filtered = filterAscii . filterShort
```

I now have need to compose these with a third filter to check if the terms are not null:

```
filter (not . null) terms
```

It has occurred to me that I am creating a chain of filters and that it would make more sense to create a single function that takes a list of filter functions and composes them in the order given.

If I recall from my reading, this is a job for an applicative functor, I believe. Can I use applicatives for this?

I am not sure how to handle the `filterShort` function where I need to `zip` each item with its one-based index before filtering.

Comment: Why everything needs to be an applicative functor these days? What happened to good old `foldl (.) id`?

Comment: How do I use that to solve my problem, especially the `zip` with index part?

Comment: This chains `[String]->[String]` functions, not `String->Bool`. BTW `ap` is no good here, `xs ap ys` applies each `x` to each `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Endo` wrapper from `Data.Monoid` to get a monoid instance that will allow you to use `mconcat` like so:

```
Prelude> :m + Data.Monoid
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t appEndo $ mconcat [Endo filterAscii, Endo filterShort]
appEndo $ mconcat [Endo filterAscii, Endo filterShort] :: [String] -> [String]
```

Answer (score 2):

In other words, you want :

```
filters :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
filters fs = filter (\a -> and $ map ($ a) fs)
```

But you should also know that a pipeline of `filter`s is very likely to be optimized by GHC (as far as I know) anyway. So it may not be worth it to create this function. Note that there will be some problems with your `filterShort` since it's not a pure filter.